# python string syntax error += operator

Tags: python, string

I get a syntax error in Python 2.7.3 like so:

```
[s += 'Orig' for s in strs]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [s += 'Orig' for s in strs]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

where strs is just a list of strings, like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

if I change the code to:

```
[s + 'Orig' for s in strs]
```

Then it works:

```
['aOrig', 'bOrig', 'cOrig', 'dOrig']
```

What's the reason behind this? Is it because the s in the list comprehension is not mutable? But it should be a temporary object that is discarded later anyway, so why not?

Also, what is the most efficient way to do what I want to do? I looked at another link: http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/ and tried to use join, but join does not do what I want; it joins a list of strings into a single string, whereas I want to append a string to a list of strings.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do that there. Python needs a value to put into the list, and assignment doesn't return a value.

Comment: List comprehensions are intended to make a new list, not be a shorthand for modifying an existing list.  If you're trying to do an in-place modification of the list, this is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething: I like the syntax of LC's so much that I wish they did!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this. `s += 'Orig'` is shorthand for `s = s + Orig`, which is an assignment. For clarity reasons, python does not allow you place assignment statements inside other statements. See the [Why can’t I use an assignment in an expression?](http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression) in the Python FAQ for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Coming from a C++ background the link explains it all.

Answer (score 7):

Assignment in Python (including `+=`) is a statement, not an expression.  You can only use expressions in a list comprehension.

What does your example with `+` not do that you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do

```
strs = [s+'Orig' for s in strs]
```

or

```
strs = map(lambda s: s+'Orig', strs)
```

I find the list comprehension (the first one) easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use it as an expression. Only through an assignment in a statement can the (+=) symbol be used.